# Pop-up spelling suggestions context menu with spell checking in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, spell-checking, sublime-text-plugin

I have coded a keybinding the the context menu with:

`command`: `context_menu`

to see the spelling suggestions but do to the way it goes to the next word and puts the cursor at the end of the word thid doesn't work. But if the cursor is inside the word or at the beginning of the word it does work. Is there an easy way to say go back one character then bring up the context menu?

Also is it possible to get `ctrl+n` and `ctrl+p` working in the context menu. Assume the context menu has the default bindings turned off.

Ended up using the suggestion of the answer below but just slightly different solution to bring you back to the beginning of the word after the command is run I did this:

```
    {
"keys": ["ctrl+alt+w"],
// Force ability to bring up context menu
"command": "chain",
"context": [ { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true } ],
"args": {
    "commands": [
        // ["move", {"by":"word", "forward": false, "extend": false}],
        ["sbp_move_word", {"direction": -1}],
        ["context_menu"],
        ["move", {"by":"wordends", "forward": true, "extend": false}],
] }
},

// Do not use "find_under_expand" if selection is made
{
"keys": ["ctrl+alt+w"],
"command": "chain",
"context": [ { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false } ],
"args": { "commands": [
            ["sbp_move_word", {"direction": -1}],
    // ["move", {"by":"word", "forward": false, "extend": false}],
    ["context_menu"], 
    ["move", {"by":"wordends", "forward": true, "extend": true}],
] }
},
```

For some reason I had problems using the regular move command but should work fine too so commented it out above the sublemacs one:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [1]

### Install:

## [**Chain Of Command**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Chain%20of%20Command)

---

---

## [2]

Add this to your key bindings:

```
// Use "find_under_expand" if no selection is made
{
        "keys": ["ctrl+super+alt+t"],
        "command": "chain",
        "context": [ { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true } ],
        "args": {
                "commands": [
                        ["find_under_expand"],
                        ["select_word_beginning"],
                        ["context_menu"],
        ] }
},

// Do not use "find_under_expand" if selection is made
{
        "keys": ["ctrl+super+alt+t"],
        "command": "chain",
        "context": [ { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "not_equal",   "operand": true } ],
        "args": {
                "commands": [
                        ["select_word_beginning"],
                        ["context_menu"],
        ] }
},
```

The `find_under_expand` command will select the word at the caret, which enables `context_menu` to consistently execute with spelling suggestions.

The second key-binding does not utilize `find_under_expand`, as this would cause multiple instances of your already selected text to be selected.

---

---

## [3]

Save this as `SelectWordBeginnings.py` somewhere in your `/Packages/` directory:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class SelectWordBeginningCommand ( sublime_plugin.TextCommand ):

    def run ( self, edit ):

        view = self.view
        selections = view.sel()

        if len ( selections ) == 0:
            return

        selection = selections[0]

        if selection.a < selection.b:
            newSelection = sublime.Region ( selection.b, selection.a )
            view.selection.clear()
            view.selection.add ( newSelection )
```

This command will invert selected regions so the caret is always at the beginning of the word.

Comment: The word is already highlighted when you select go to next misspelling but the issue is that the cursor is at the end of the word. Whether it is highlighted or isn't it needs to move the cursor to the beginning of the word then pop-up the context menu. Maybe instead of `find_under_expand` is there a function that moves cursor to the beginning of the word?

Comment: I use sublemacs so they have a move word command but how do I pass in the `args` to it: `["sbp_move_word", "args":{"direction": -1}],`. This is the command I tried.

Comment: @JSpen:  I just implemented a new workaround and can verify that it always brings up spelling suggestions.

Comment: @JSpen: Also, what command or plugin are you using to navigate misspelled words? I haven't really used the spell-checking feature...

Comment: The default program in Sublime Text 3 has a spell checker built-in. That is the only program I can really find for mispelled words but no good way to navigate and get selections. That is why I wanted this feature. Then I also use the `Google Spell Check` package if I don't know the spelling. It has to query google so not the fastest.

Comment: I'll accept this result because it works but also check my question as already ended up figuriong out a solution.